# MYSQL count selected results from multiple keys and insert if not there

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery, sql-insert

I am trying to insert a new row based off a select search result.
Here is the current query.

```
DECLARE @count INT;
SET @count = ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tagged_products
                WHERE
                  company_id = 1 AND
                  product_id = 141 AND
                  category_id = 3)
IF @count <= 0
THEN
  INSERT INTO tagged_products (company_id, product_id, category_id)
  VALUES (1, 141, 3)
END IF
```

The current error I get is:
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF @count <= 0 THEN INSERT INTO tagged_products (company_' at line 6`

How could the query, insert the row if there was not matching select query otherwise it should ignore it?

Thanks :)

Comment: If flow control statements are only allowed in stored programs(procedure,function,trigger,event) is your code in such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to insert a row if it does not yet exist. The simplest approach is to have a `unique` constraint (or index) on the 3 table columns, then use `insert ... on duplicate key`:

```
INSERT INTO tagged_products (company_id, product_id, category_id)
VALUES (1, 141, 3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE company_id = VALUES(company_id) -- no-op
```

If you can't create the unique key, then you can use `insert ... select ... where not exists ...`:

```
INSERT INTO tagged_products (company_id, product_id, category_id)
SELECT 1, 141, 3
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tagged_products WHERE company_id = 1 AND product_id = 141 AND category_id = 3)
```

Comment: Thanks @GMB, I couldn't create a unique key. Really appreciate your help, Stay Awesome!